# Having trouble with posting to an spring boot entity table via angular, when adding new arguments in ts

Tags: angular, spring, many-to-many, httprequest, angular-reactive-forms

I have this spring boot controller functions in the BidPerContestController class :

```java
@PostMapping
    public void postBid(@RequestBody BidPerContest bid){

        bidPerContestService.setBidPerContest(bid);


    }
    
      @PatchMapping("/patch/{id}/{teamN}/{userN}/{contestN}")
    public void patchBid(@PathVariable(name = "contestN") String contestN,
                         @PathVariable(name = "id") long id,
                         @PathVariable(name = "teamN") String teamN,
                         @PathVariable(name = "userN") String userN) {


       bidPerContestService.getBidPerContest(id).setContest(contestService.getContestByName(contestN));
       bidPerContestService.getBidPerContest(id).setTeam(teamService.getTeam(teamN));
       bidPerContestService.getBidPerContest(id).setUser((User) userService.getUserByEmail(userN));




    }
```

Via angular I am using the function addBet to create a post request creating a BidPerContest new entry in the table than, patching the bid so that the contest,user and team are binded to the BidPerContest. (.ts file)

```ts
 addBetOnTeam() {

   this.http.post((this.bidUrl),this.bidCreateForm.value).subscribe(result => {

              console.log(result);
              console.log(this.bidCreateForm.value);

            });


    this.http.patch(('/patch/ '+ this.getLastBid() + '/' + this.objectList[0].teams[0].name + '/' + this.getUser() + '/' + this.objectList[0].name),null);

    console.log(this.http.get('/'+this.getLastBid()),this.objectList[0].teams[0].name, this.objectList[0].name);

  }

  getLastBid(){

    let last : any;

    last = this.http.get(this.bidUrl+'/last').subscribe(result=>console.log(result));

    return last.id

  }
```

posting works, patching doesn`t :)), bidContestForm(group) contains only form-control bid inside.

The object-list is a list of contests, the contest list containing the path variables, needed, working accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the subscription :

```
    this.http.patch(('/patch/ '+ this.getLastBid() + '/' + this.objectList[0].teams[0].name + '/' + this.getUser() + '/' + this.objectList[0].name),null).subscribe(result => {
//you code
   });
```